# Evaluating $\int \frac{dx}{x^3+x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^3+x+1}$$

I have no idea how to solve this. How do I evaluate it?

Any advice, hint or well-thought solution will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give any more context? For example, is this related to an application, or is it just a problem from a textbook? It doesn't seem like there's any solution to the indefinite integral that doesn't involve simply factorizing the denominator  (letting, say, $\omega_{1}$, $\omega_{2}$, $\omega_{3}$ be the roots) into three linear terms and splitting into partial fractions.

Comment: Wolfram isn't liking this, it seems horrendous.

Comment: Not pleasant! Let the real root be $\alpha$. This can be expressed exactly in trigonometric form.  Then you can factor as $x-\alpha$ times an irreducible quadratic  $Q(x)$. Then use partial fractions to express as $\frac{A}{x-\alpha}+\frac{Bx+C}{Q(x)}$. Now things are standard.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: I don't know why I forgot that there had to be at least one real root, but I did, so +1 to you for pointing that out.

Comment: @WillR it is just a problem from a assignment.

Comment: Why the down vote? I thought it a good question especially as the denominator looks so deceptively innocent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,\zeta_3$ be the roots of $x^3+x+1$. We have:

$$ \text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^3+z+1},z=\zeta_i\right) = \frac{1}{3\zeta_i^2+1},\tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \frac{1}{z^3+z+1}=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{1}{3\zeta_i^2+1}\cdot\frac{1}{z-\zeta_i} \tag{2} $$
and:
$$ \int \frac{dz}{z^3+z+1} = C+\sum_{i=1}^{3}\frac{\log(z-\zeta_i)}{3\zeta_i^2+1}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Maybe one should add that this only holds as long as our path of integration avoids any of the singularities...

Comment: @tired: obviously, when computing a definite integral related with such a function we have to be careful about that, and in choosing the $log$ branches, but the *formal* primitive does not care about such subtleties.

Comment: i'm aware of that, but many people stumble upon such subtilities and therefore i think it is a good idea to mention that.